# two python class interacting with each other

Tags: python, oop, matplotlib

I have the python class:

```
class CSerieTemporal:
    txtXLabel = "Data"
    txtYLabel = "Cotação"
    txtTitle = ""
    dLocator = False
    mLocator = False
    ligarGrid = True
    legenda=""
    cores = ['royalblue', 'darkgreen', 'lime']
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
    destacarPrimeira = False

    def __init__(self,dados):
        self.dados = dados
        self.meuymax = np.amax(self.dados[:, 1:]) * 1.03
        self.meuymin = np.amin(self.dados[:, 1:]) * 0.97

    def montar(self):
        ax = plt.subplot(111)
        for i in range(1,len(self.dados[1])):
            if self.destacarPrimeira:
                ax.plot(self.dados[:,0],self.dados[:,i],self.cores[i-1],linewidth = 3)
                self.destacarPrimeira = False
            else:
                ax.plot(self.dados[:, 0], self.dados[:, i], self.cores[i - 1])
        plt.xticks(rotation=30)
        plt.xlabel(self.txtXLabel)
        plt.ylabel(self.txtYLabel)
        plt.title(self.txtTitle)
        ax.grid(self.ligarGrid)

        if self.dLocator != False:
            ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(DayLocator(self.dLocator))
        if self.mLocator != False:
            ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator(self.mLocator))

        ax.set_xlim(xmin=self.dados[0,0],xmax=self.dados[-1,0])
        ax.set_ylim(ymin=self.meuymin, ymax = self.meuymax)

        box = ax.get_position()
        ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0 + box.height*0.25, box.width, box.height*0.75])
        plt.legend(self.legenda,loc = "lower left", bbox_to_anchor=(0,-0.4))

    def salvar(self,filename):
        self.montar()
        plt.savefig(filename)

    def mostrar(self):
        self.montar()
        plt.show()
```

TO creating plots using matplotlib. But, if I create two instances of this class of different parameters like:

```
graf2 = CSerieTemporal(np_fundos)
graf2.legenda = ["Brazil CDS 5y"]
graf2.cores = ["royalblue"]
graf2.mLocator = [6,12]
graf2.txtXLabel = ""
graf2.txtYLabel = ""
graf2.txtTitle = "Brazil CDS 5 years"
graf2.ligarGrid = False
graf3 = CSerieTemporal(np_fundos)
graf3.legenda = ["Petrobras 5,093% 01/15/2030","Petrobras 8,75%  05/23/2026"]
graf3.cores = ["royalblue","darkgreen"]
graf3.txtTitle = "Petrobras yield curve inversion"
graf3.txtXLabel = ""
graf3.txtYLabel = "Yield [%]"
graf3.ligarGrid = False
```

i get the classes mixed up when I use the function to show the plots. What I am doing wrong? for instance, the first plot works as expected, but the second one, the image has wrong proportions, but, if I comment the first one, the second works as expected.

Comment: Most, if not all, of those attribute assignments should take place inside `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

In python when you declare class like this:

```
class CSerieTemporal:
   txtXLabel = "Data"
```

`txtXLabel` is a variable in the class itself that is it is shared by *all instances* of that class. So if you change it like this:

```
a = CSerieTemporal()
b = CSerieTemporal()
a.txtXLabel = 'aaa'
```

then `b.txtXLabel` will be `aaa` as well.

In order to have instance private copy you need to declare it in `__init__` method like this:

```
class CSerieTemporal:
   def __init__(self):
       self.txtXLabel = "Data"
```